# Calculating Average Cycles per Instruction given Execution Time, Instruction Count, and Clock Rate

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, cpu-cycles

So I'm learning Computer Architecture where we have to take into account different processors and their clocks, and I can't help but feel that my calculations are off when calculating average CPI. For one such process, I am given:

- an Instruction Count of 1.0E9
- an Execution Time of 1.5s for Compiler A's program
- and a Clock Rate of 8.0E9 Hz for the processor.

My reworked equation is `CPI = (Execution Time * Clock Rate)/Instruction Count`.

Plugging in the values, I got that the average CPI for Compiler A's program is 12. However, this is a lot higher than other practice problems. I was wondering if my calculations were correct or not, and if so, how come the CPI is so high?

Comment: Result looks correct. It's a theoretical example, so I wouldn't worry about being too high. Heck, a division on an actual x86 cpu may take more than 12 cycles and that's not even accounting for memory accesses.

Comment: @Jester Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If this were real instead of a made up random example:

I'd expect an 8GHz CPU to be *heavily* pipelined, and thus have high penalties for branch mispredicts and other stalls.  And probably higher latency for more complex instructions.  (Presumably still single-cycle latency for `add` and other simple ALU instructions; clocking so high that you can't do that only makes sense if you want 8GHz for marketing, not real performance.)

Also, for a given speed of DRAM, a cache miss has a basically fixed time in nanoseconds.  With a faster core clock, that's many more core cycles spend waiting for the same cache miss (i.e. more memory latency for out-of-order execution to try to hide).

See also [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) - this would be a full "speed demon" design, opposite of "brainiac".

---

But even then, a CPI of 12 probably wouldn't be typical (e.g. for SPECint2017) on any sane design anyone would bother building.  But remember, this is for one specific program.  A very high CPI (low IPC) is also a sign of inefficient software (or at least doing something that's unavoidably slow), e.g. spending a lot of time walking linked lists that miss in cache.  The address for the next load depends on the previous load, so it can't even start until it arrives from some outer cache or even all the way from memory.

(Other data structures also involve pointer chasing, e.g. binary trees.  Searching a huge binary tree involves both pointer-chasing and (usually) branch mispredicts.  Binary searching a flat array, or an implicit tree where the nodes are at known array positions, allows software prefetch of the 2 possibilities ahead of the next step, using extra bandwidth to reduce latency by taking advantage of memory-level parallelism that most HW is capable of.)

---

Or of course since this is only a theoretical example with no implication of sanity, the CPU can be as stupidly inefficient as we want: maybe it's microcoded (and not pipelined), like original 8086 and other microprocessors of that era, and executes instructions by following microcoded steps that each take a clock cycle.  (e.g. Z80 performance details were known in terms of internal states vs. clock cycles, and normal instructions took several).

---

Or maybe it's an architecture with old-school Cray-style SIMD vector instructions, where one instruction (with a couple pointer inputs) might replace a whole loop over arrays of floating-point numbers.  (So high-end CPUs can take advantage of wider data paths without needing different machine code like we do for modern short-vector SIMD like x86 SSE/AVX/AVX512 does to take advantage of new HW with wider SIMD add/mul/FMA units.)

Comment: That is what I was thinking; the processor would have to be really bad if the CPI was that high. This is just what the problem gave me, and I kept getting 12 each time.

Comment: @Zakenmaru: You could easily write a program that runs 12 CPI on a Skylake or Zen (very much "brainiac" designs).  For example, do searches on a binary tree, bottlenecking on cache-miss *latency* (not throughput, low memory-level parallelism), and on branch mispredicts.  Having the CPU be really bad is only one of multiple ways to explain this.

Comment: @Zakenmaru: But yes, typical CPI is under 1.0 for mainstream CPUs on workloads like SPECint2017 / SPECfp2017 (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322745869_A_Workload_Characterization_of_the_SPEC_CPU2017_Benchmark_Suite shows a Haswell Xeon hitting about 1.7 IPC = 1 / 1.7 CPI).  More often people talk about IPC, perhaps especially for superscalar designs. So anyway, choice of workload is more than sufficient to explain a CPI anywhere from 0.2 to 20, or over 100 if we're talking about hand-crafted assembly or an FP workload that needs a microcode assist for sub-normal results on every insn